# Error when use mixins in Magento2 on widget

Tags: magento2, mixins

I want to override function in `Magento_Checkout/js/region-updater`

So in template child:

```
'Magento_Checkout/js/region-updater': {
            'js/Magento_Checkout/region-updater-mixin': true,
        },
```

And inside mixin:

```
define([], function () {
    return function (widget) {
        'use strict';
        console.log('update')
        $.widget('mage.regionUpdater', widget, {
            _updateRegion: function (country) {
                ...... changes here
            },
        })
        return $.mage.regionUpdater
    }
})
```

I can see console log. However i cant see my changes reflected and i get error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'widget')`

The line is:
`$.widget('mage.regionUpdater', widget, {`

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Can some one write solution for this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone had similar problem.
Solution is to import also jquery to file. Component must be in jquery namespace.